# (Android - Gradle) Jacoco coverage not excluding some class files

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

Im trying to create a Jacoco report using a Gradle task for an Android Studio project. I want to exclude some non-tested files from the report but they still appearing on the web report.

This is the Gradle task I've defined:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    // Use this version for upper ones are broken (with Gradle)
    // https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/288
    toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
}

def coverageSourceDirs = [
        'src/main/java/....',
]

task createJacocoReport(type: JacocoReport) {
    println ":${project.name}:Generating Jacoco reports"
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        xml.destination = "${buildDir}/jacocoReport.xml"
        csv.enabled = true
        csv.destination = "${buildDir}/jacocoReport.csv"
        html.enabled = true
        html.destination = "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
    }
    classDirectories = fileTree(dir: './build/intermediates/classes/release',
            excludes: ['**/R$*.class',
                      '**/R.class',
                      '**/android/**/*.class',
                      '**/google/**/*.class',
                      '**/Activities/*.class',
                      '**/Fragments/*.class',
                      '**/Views/*.class',
                      '**/NativeImplementations/*.class',
                      '**/BuildConfig.class',
                      '**/CameraDefaultConfig.class'])

    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files("./build/jacoco/testReleaseUnitTest.exec")
}
```

And I launch this task with:

```
check.finalizedBy(createJacocoReport)
```

Anyone has an idea about what's happening? I'm using Android Studio 2.1.1 with the Gradle Plugin 2.1.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this issue replacing the excludes list with the includes one. Even though I don't understand what's the cause of this, if anyone has an idea...

Comment: Can you please how your includes list look like? Do you still use the dir property? Thanks

Comment: I believe the reason is that putting something in `excludes` treats it as having 0% coverage, and that was throwing off your total percentages.